# InvalidArgumentError when yielding List of Dicts inside TensorFlow 2.3.1 Dataset graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, dictionary, tensorflow-datasets

## Problem Statement

I have to read from Google Cloud Storage, several JSON Lines files `.jsonl`. In order to do this, I have created a dataset from the records I want to read, which is a `numpy array` containing `[[<gs:// url>, id], ...]` where `id` is row number to check which line is train/test/validation.

## Code

The main function, which creates the `TF Dataset` from a `generator` which yields the previously described `np.ndarray` and then runs a map function to download and parse the file is:

```py
def load_dataset(records: np.ndarray) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """Create Tensorflow Dataset MapDataset (generator) from a list of gs:// data URL.

    Args:
        records (np.ndarray): List of strings, which are gs://<foo>/foo<N>/*.jsonl.gz files

    Returns:
        tf.data.Dataset: MapDataset generator which can be used for training Keras models.
    """
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: _generator(records), (tf.string, tf.int8))
    return dataset


def _generator(records):
    for r in records:
        yield r[0], r[1]
```

As you can see, the `generator` is simply iterating through the `np.ndarray` to get `url` and a `'line index'`

Then I have to `load and preprocess` the file from the URL to get a list of the `json -> Dict` objects.

```py
def _load_and_preprocess(filepath, selected_sample):
    """Read a file GCS or local path and process it into a tensor

    Args:
        path (tensor): path string, pointer to GCS or local path

    Returns:
        tensor: processed input
    """
    sample_raw_input = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    uncompressed_inputs = tf.py_function(_get_uncompressed_inputs, [sample_raw_input], tf.string)
    sample = tf.py_function(_load_sampled_sample, [uncompressed_inputs, selected_sample], tf.float32) #This `tf.float32` is definitely wrong
    return sample #This is not a tensor, but a List of Dictionaries which I will process later


def _get_uncompressed_inputs(record):
    return zlib.decompress(record.numpy(), 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)


def _load_sampled_sample(inputs: Iterable, selected_sample: List[int]) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    if not tf.executing_eagerly():
        raise RuntimeError("TensorFlow must be executing eagerly.")
    inputs = inputs.numpy()
    selected_sample = selected_sample.numpy()
    sample = _load__sampled_sample_from_jsonl(inputs, selected_sample)
    return sample


def _load__sampled_sample_from_jsonl(jsonl: bytes, selected_sample: List[int]) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
    json_lines = _read_jsonl(jsonl).split("\n")
    sample = list()
    for n, sample_json in enumerate(json_lines):
        sample_obj = _read_json(sample_json) if n in selected_sample else None
        if sample_obj:
            sample.append(sample_obj)
    return sample


def _read_jsonl(jsonl: bytes) -> str:
    return jsonl.decode()
```

## Executing

I then create the dataset with the above code, and try to retrieve a single sample from it to test.

```py
val_ds = load_dataset(validation_records)
samples = tf.data.experimental.get_single_element(
    val_ds
) # This should be a list of Dicts
```

Which `raises`:

```
InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: Attempt to convert a value ({...}) with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.
# ... are the dict values, which is really big so I've shortened it to `...`
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 242, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 140, in __call__
    outputs = [

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 141, in <listcomp>
    _maybe_copy_to_context_device(self._convert(x, dtype=dtype),

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 120, in _convert
    return ops.convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1499, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 338, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 263, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 275, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 300, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)

  File "/home/victor/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value ({...}) with an unsupported type (<class 'dict'>) to a Tensor.
# ... are the dict values, which is really big so I've shortened it to `...`


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc_1}}]] [Op:DatasetToSingleElement]
```

## Conclusion

Is there any way I can work with List of Dicts without Eager execution (which is not allowed from TF Dataset)?

This list of dicts is not the input for my model, however, I simply cannot work with it in the `preprocessing` function because this error is raised before passing the values to any other function.

## Additional Informations:

- Python Version: `3.8`
- Tensorflow Version: `2.3.1`

Comment: The [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor#building_datasets_with_ragged_tensors) states "Note: Dataset.from_generator does not support ragged tensors yet, but support will be added soon". I think it is worth exploring an option where you get rid of the `from_generator` function.

Comment: What is `RaggerTensor`? Do you have any suggestion on how to get rid of the `from_generator` fn? I tried `from_tensor_slices` but it does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have fixed it with running eagerly a `dataset.map` function:

`dataset.map(lambda file, samples: tf.py_function(_load_and_preprocess, [file, samples], tf.variant))`

Which is described here: [How can you map values in a tf.data.Dataset using a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659374/how-can-you-map-values-in-a-tf-data-dataset-using-a-dictionary)